# TCPDF table on multiple page with margin

Tags: php, html, html-table, tcpdf

I have a table which changes dynamically. So, the table can be on multiple pages.

I successfully change the page without breaking row but I have a problem concerning the header of the document. The table continues on the second page but begin at the top disregarding the margin set  for the logo in the document.

Here's my code

```
$html = '<br/>
        <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5" border="0" style="text-align:center;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" style="border-left:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-bottom:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-right:0.5px solid #1d2e5c;" bgcolor="#1d2e5c"><font color="#ffffff">&Eacute;QUIPEMENTS ET LOGICIELS</font></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width:10%; border-left:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-bottom:0.5px solid #1d2e5c;">Qt&eacute;</th>
                    <th style="width:50%; border-left:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-bottom:0.5px solid #1d2e5c;">Description</th>
                    <th style="width:20%; border-left:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-bottom:0.5px solid #1d2e5c;">Prix</th>
                    <th style="width:20%; border-left:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-bottom:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-right:0.5px solid #1d2e5c;">Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>';

foreach( $equipements as $row ) {
    $quant = $row['Qte'];
    $priceUnit = (ISSET($row['AutrePrix']) && $row['AutrePrix'] != 0) ? $row['AutrePrix'] : $row['Prix'];
    $totalEquip = $quant * $priceUnit;
    $totalAllEquip += $totalEquip;
    $html .= '<tr nobr="true">
                <td style="width:10%; border-left:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-bottom:0.5px solid #1d2e5c;">' . $quant . '</td>
                <td style="width:50%; border-left:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-bottom:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; text-align: left;">' . $row['Nom'] . '</td>
                <td style="width:20%; border-left:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-bottom:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; text-align: right;">' . number_format($priceUnit, 2, '.', ' ') . '<font size="-2"> $</font></td>
                <td style="width:20%; border-left:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-bottom:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-right:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; text-align: right;">' . number_format($totalEquip, 2, '.', ' ') . '<font size="-2"> $</font></td>
              </tr>';
}
$html .= '<tr>
            <td colspan="3"></td>
            <td style="width:20%; border-left:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-bottom:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; border-right:0.5px solid #1d2e5c; text-align: right;" bgcolor="#1d2e5c"><font color="#ffffff">' . number_format($totalAllEquip, 2, '.', ' ') . '</font><font color="#ffffff" size="-2"> $</font></td>
          </tr>
        </table>';

$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, false, false, '');
```

**EDIT : 2016-06-01**

I use the tcpdf library : sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf and the tcpdf_config.php file. The command I use to set header data is :

```
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));
```

Comment: how do you set your header, margin and logo? Maybe the code can help for better solution

Comment: I use the tcpdf library : https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcpdf/ and the tcpdf_config.php file. The command I use to set header data is : $pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE, PDF_HEADER_STRING, array(0,64,255), array(0,64,128));

Comment: do you already add `$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);`?

Comment: yes, I already have that code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because all the configurations that I had set up didn't work (I had set up everything like the example here : http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.phps - http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.pdf), I have finally set up a counter for the maximum of rows in a page and then, I've added a new page and after, I've continued on the other page.

That was the easiest way I've found (I was hurry to find a solution)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your page margin and auto page break

```
// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
```

for example you can take a look at http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.phps
and the result example at http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_048.pdf

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I've built my page using this example. So, I already have these lines of code and it doesn't work. What I have done, is to set a maximum number of rows and then add page and continue on the other page...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem to generate a multi-page salarysheet and I solved it by removing all HTML tags except `<table><thead><tbody>`

I think it will helpful to other.